# Transmission will start running as soon as I log in

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, startup, transmission

So that's pretty much it. Transmission will start running as soon as I boot my pc and log in and I would very much appreciate if it would just stop doing that. 
No particularly problematic, but quite annoying.

Can someone help out?

Cheers

PS: Im running 14.04 with the Xfce GUI, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Remove it from the startup applications by searching "Startup Applications" in the Dash and unchecking Transmission.

Comment: I've already tried that. Transmission is not on the "Startup Applications" list.